# Highcharts jQuery rendering problem - all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a strange problem whilst trying to build a stacked column chart using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

When the chart renders, **the columns don't display, until, you resize the browser** in anyway, causing the chart to redraw. (I think)!
The rest of the chart displays (axis, titles, etc) but not the columns themselves.

I get the same behaviour in IE, Firefox and chrome.

I have put my code on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/173/
Load it up and you should see no data, resize the browser window and "tada", the data appears (rather the columns appear)!

Any help on this one would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This problem is back in Highcharts 2.3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove line `chart.render();`

When HighCharts constructor is called there's no need to call `render` implicitly.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem - Highcharts JS v2.1.5 (2011-06-22) does not work with jQuery 1.7.1

After changing to jQuery 1.6.1 (The last stable release I used) it worked.
Someone should check other versions of jQuery.

Comment: I also upgraded to Highcharts 2.1.9 and it works with jQuery 1.7.1 now

Comment: I also had a jquery/highcharts version problem. Upgrading both highcharts and jquery to the latest version made the problem go away.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem - after loading the page, the chart didn't display the lines (only the title and legend). After any browser resize or also zooming the chart suddenly appeared.

The problem was with jQuery > 1.7 (my version now is 1.8.2)
Update of the Highcharts to the latest version (v2.3.3 (2012-10-04)) fixed the problem (and also other small issues)

Comment: I am so glad you posted this!  I'm on 2.3.5 and the problem is back. I downgraded to Highcharts 2.3.3, and it works with jquery 1.9.1

Answer (score 3):

You needn't change any version of Highcharts or Jquery, if you `resize()` your div-container at the end of your script.

For example:

```
$('#div').resize();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery 1.7.2 + HighCharts 3.0.2 the problem was solved by using:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                //When is chart ready?
                $(window).resize(); 
            }
        }        
    }, ..
```

This is the almost the same as @revo, but uses the 'window' object instead of 'document'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late , but i had the same problem with jQuery 1.9.1 and didn't want to downgrade  it for Highcharts with dotnet.highcharts.

if you crate a new Highchart there 
e.g.

```
.InitChart(new Chart
 {
    DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line,
    MarginRight = 130,
    MarginBottom = 25,
    ClassName = "chart",
    Events = new ChartEvents { Load = "function(event) { $(document).resize(); }" }
  }) .....
```

You also can use it

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                //When is chart ready?
                $(document).resize(); 
            }
        }        
    }, ..
```

.
the events line is what you need then you render your chart

I hope it helped, i had some hours to figure it out how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The "not so delicate" solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835572/highcharts-ng-size-does-fill-div-until-inspect-element), is what finally solved it for me.

```
setTimeout(function() {
                $(window).resize();
            }, 0);
```

Using highcharts with a wrapper called DjangoChartit, with Python Django.